# Mobile Safari download issue : The operation couldn’t be completed. (webkitblobresource error 1.)

Tags: angular, mobile-safari

My Angular application has a pdf download option. When i run my application in Iphone(IOS 12) Safari browser I get the following error message as shown in the image

How can i resolve it?

[image: ios_safari_issue]

Comment: Hey, did you find the solution?

Comment: @RezaRahmati Not yet

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: Can you please give an URL to test with, or at least an example URL?

Answer (score 11):

If you are injecting an ancor tag into DOM programmatically as your solution, make sure you do not clear that up too soon.

For me 100ms worked fine but since it's invisible either way I chose 1 second delay on clearing DOM up.

Example code:

```
this.fileApi.download(<your args>).subscribe((data: Blob) => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.style.display = 'none';
    a.href = url;

    // the filename you want
    a.download = <your filename>;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();

    setTimeout(() => {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    }, 1000);
  })
```

Comment: how about open that file to download / new tab ?
a.target = "_blank"; seems to broke it and a.download = title; not working for ios

Comment: This is not the case here since the actual download occurs via API request and as a Blob object. For example if user has to be authorized with an access token.

Comment: so for now there is no way to open blob in new tab / download GJ IOS